# How do i practically check that in background transfer service ,transfers continue in the background even if the app is suspended, exits, or crashes

Tags: ios, ios7

I have implemented sample tutorial for background transfer service given in below link also edited the name of the scheme and selected the check box for "Background Fetch ... Launch due to a background fetch event"
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Background_Transfer_Service_Tutorial

This sample works fine.It downloads image before app starts.
If next time when app is restarted and kept in background it downloads image as well.
Now If I  remove the app from multitasking card view then app does not download the image when start app again.
I have read below description in apple doc

- (NSURLSessionConfiguration *)backgroundSessionConfiguration:(NSString *)identifier
  Parameters
  identifier
  An identifier for the new session configuration that is unique for your app. Your app can retrieve the download or the upload response later by creating a new background session with the same identifier.
  Discussion
  Sessions created with configuration objects returned by this method are called background sessions. These sessions differ from other sessions in the following ways:

Upload and download tasks in background sessions are performed by an external daemon instead of by the app itself. As a result, the transfers continue in the background even if the app is suspended, exits, or crashes.

Need to know how do I check the transfers continue in the background even if the app is suspended, exits, or crashes??

Answer (score 1):

Add `exit(0);` to your code immediately after the download starts. Then see if it still continues downloading or not.